# Json request string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i have this code that works but im pretty sure there is a better way to do this, can you guys help?

```
jsrqs = 2022-02-08 14:01:56,048 sdc-web-sockets-pp /moe.com/SMART/logs/srf/srf-web-sockets.log: 2022-02-08 14:01:50,308 srf-web-sockets-pp-1 INFO [null:-1] (executor-thread-19) Op16 - Station : id-00003:vdeURRi8v8evU8AZWEnIwtbrucvjdeZyJL42, MessageId: a8a3e920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c904565fadef, request message: {"action":"Boot","messageId":"a8d3r920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c9074d5fadef","type":"CALL","uniqueId":"a8a3e920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c9074d5fadef","payload":"{"Vendor":"vendorname","PointModel":"pointname","PointSerialNumber":"123456789","firmwareVersion":"1.1.1.8"}"}
```

this is my code, it works but its "ugly"

```
                if "BOOT" in jsrqs.upper():
                    j1,j2ff = jsrqs.split(r"payload")
                    j2f = j2ff.replace("\\", "")
                    j2a = j2f[3:]
                    size = len(j2a)
                    j2 = j2a[:size - 2]
                    stud_obj = json.loads(j2)

                    inp_vendor.delete('1.0', END)
                    inp_model.delete('1.0', END)
                    inp_sn.delete('1.0', END)
                    inp_firmware.delete('1.0', END)

                    inp_firmware.insert("1.0", str(stud_obj['firmwareVersion']))
                    inp_model.insert("1.0", str(stud_obj['PointModel']))
                    inp_sn.insert("1.0", str(stud_obj['PointSerialNumber']))
                    inp_vendor.insert("1.0", str(stud_obj['PointVendor']))
```

Comment: if it works codereview SE might be a better place to ask. Also you don't provide what the expected result should be

Comment: If the code works, you can try to make it more concise but that's not really needed for this. I would suggest you use better variable names since any fresh set of eyes (especially yours after a few weeks/months/years of not seeing the code) won't be able to understand what `j1`, `j2ff`, `j2f`, `j2a`, and `j2`

Answer (score 0):

I think my code would help u,splitting the response body where we need. worked for me

```
import json

jsrqs = """2022-02-08 14:01:56,048 sdc-web-sockets-pp /moe.com/SMART/logs/srf/srf-web-sockets.log: 2022-02-08 14:01:50,308 srf-web-sockets-pp-1 INFO [null:-1] (executor-thread-19) Op16 - Station : id-00003:vdeURRi8v8evU8AZWEnIwtbrucvjdeZyJL42, MessageId: a8a3e920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c904565fadef, request message: {"action":"Boot","messageId":"a8d3r920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c9074d5fadef","type":"CALL","uniqueId":"a8a3e920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c9074d5fadef","payload":"{"Vendor":"vendorname","PointModel":"pointname","PointSerialNumber":"123456789","firmwareVersion":"1.1.1.8"}"}"""

if "BOOT" in jsrqs.upper():
    resp = json.loads(str(jsrqs.split('payload":"')[1][:-2]))

    print(resp['Vendor'])
    print(resp['PointModel'])
    print(resp['firmwareVersion'])
    print(resp['PointSerialNumber'])
```

Comment: thanks, get error cant read from double quotes

Comment: check your code again, use single qoutes to wrap double qouted strings

Comment: my jsrqs came from a textbox get its a var, how can i had the """?

Comment: jsrqs = e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c")